# Pillow - Transparency over non-transparent image with paste

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Let me prefix with a disclaimer that I am clueless when it comes to imaging/graphics all together, so maybe I'm lacking a fundamental understanding with something here.

I'm trying to paste an image (`game_image`) to my base image (`image`) with a transparent overlay (`overlay_image`) over top to add some darkening for the text.

Here's an example of the expected result:

[image]

Here's an example of what my current code generates:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

# base image sizing specific to Twitter recommended
base_image_size = (1600, 900)
base_image_mode = "RGBA"
base_image_background_color = (0, 52, 66)

image = Image.new(base_image_mode, base_image_size, base_image_background_color)

# game_image is the box art image on the left side of the card
game_image = Image.open("hunt.jpg")
image.paste(game_image)

# overlay_image is the darkened overlay over the left side of the card
overlay_image = Image.new(base_image_mode, base_image_size, (0, 0, 0))
overlay_image.putalpha(128)

# x position should be negative 50% of base canvas size
image.paste(overlay_image, (-800, 0), overlay_image)
image.save("test_image.png", format="PNG")
```

You can see that the game image sort of inherits the transparency from the overlay. I suspect it has something to do with the `mask` added in my paste above, but I tried looking into what masking is & its just beyond my understanding in any context I find it in.

Any help on understanding why this occurs and/or how I can resolve is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are super close... All you need, is to use `Image.alpha_composite` instead of `paste`. So, the last two lines of your code should be:

```
image = Image.alpha_composite(image, overlay_image)
image.save("test_image.png", format="PNG")
```

Comment: Worked perfect, I'll read the docs on that to try and grasp the difference, thanks a lot!